# Binding data to a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am new to DataBindings. I am trying to bind a list of files (more properly, a `IEnumerable<FileInfo>`) to a `ListView` in C# (Visual Studio 2010). Here is what I am trying to do (I have done a lot more trials, this is the simplest to post):

My XAML is (no resources / databindings are defined elsewhere):

```
        <ListView
            Name="lvInvoices" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            Width="Auto" MinWidth="150" MinHeight="100" Margin="10">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="#" Width="Auto"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Fichero" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=SourceFile}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Importe" Width="Auto"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

My ' item' class is this. I know I am not firing PropertyChanged events, by now I just want to populate the list.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SPInvoiceLoader
{
  public class Invoice : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public Invoice()
    {
    }

    public Invoice(FileInfo srcFile)
    {
      this.SourceFile = srcFile;
    }
    public FileInfo SourceFile { get; private set; }
    public int SpId { get; set; }
    public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Nif { get; set; }
    public bool Signed { get; set; }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  }
}
```

And the code where the DataContext is set is:

```
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> pdfFiles = dir.EnumerateFiles("*.pdf");
    pdfFiles = pdfFiles.OrderBy(f => f.Name);
    ObservableCollection<Invoice> coll = new ObservableCollection<Invoice>();
    foreach (FileInfo pdfFile in pdfFiles)
    {
      coll.Add(new Invoice(pdfFile));
    }
    this.lvInvoices.DataContext = coll;
```

I have tried setting `pdfFiles` both as a local variable and an instance member, but it does not work either way.

The effect is that no items are updated at all, the list continues to be empty.

Any suggestion? I am pretty new at this so don't rule out stupid mistakes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try setting ItemsSource on the ListView to {Binding} so it knows to pick up its items from its DataContext so: ItemsSource="{Binding}"

Comment: @tomasmcguinness You were right, thanks. Put that as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting ItemsSource on the ListView to {Binding} so it knows to pick up its items from its DataContext so: ItemsSource="{Binding}"

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution, can be much better (using view models)...

You have to make your ObservableCollection a property:

```
public ObservableCollection<Invoice> MyInvoices { get; set; }
```

In the `Loaded` event of your user control initialize your collection:

```
this.MyInvoices = ....
```

In the same event set the DataContext of your user control to itself:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Now in XAML do:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyInvoices}"></ListView>
```

In that way when you will add more things to your user control just add properties and you have ready the bindings.

Comment: It worked too... in fact I like this option as it was more generic than the other two (althougth they did provide a correct answer, too).

Answer (score 2):

You want to assign your ObservableCollection to the ItemsSource property of the ListView not to the DataContext.